# Are the MSAL claims constants available in a package somewhere?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've moved my authentication to MSAL and I want to examine my claims on the client side to see, for example, the object ID that I have in Azure B2C (and thus, give my client an identity).

On the server, the objectId claim appears to be returned as:

{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 63fd3d89-26ff-4934-907c-5e6c9da07c45}

The URI "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" is a known claim and can be accessed using Claims.Name and I can use a statement like this to extract the objectId from the claims:

```
    Guid userId = new(this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

But on the client, the objectId claim is returned using the 'oid' URI and I can't use the same kind of pre-defined claims that I can on the server.

Obviously I can define these as constants in a shared module, but I can't be the only one trying to parse claims from the client side. Is there an analog of 'ClaimTypes' for MSAL on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and found the `ClaimConstants.ObjectId` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.claimconstants.objectid?view=azure-dotnet)) to match the `oid` claim type (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier`).

```
Guid userId = new(this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimConstants.ObjectId));
```

It's part of the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package.

Comment: Too bad.  Microsoft.Identity.Web isn't availble for Xamarin applications.